# Calculating constant velocity from friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, velocity

I'm unsure if my Book is wrong.

Either way, we send a pinball through a cylinder filled with oil, the forces that apply are.

Fpinball = 15,8 ∙ 10^−6 ∙ 9,82 = 5,69 ∙ 10^−5N

Foil =  ∙  ∙  = 0,88 ∙ 10^3 ∙ 9,82 ∙ 6,4 ∙ 10^−9 = 5,53 ∙ 10^−5N

The book says the pinball should travel at constant velocity when it hits $4 \text{ cm/s}$. At that point the friction force is $10\cdot 10^{-5}\text{ N}$.

Here is where it gets tricky, the book says that Force down - Force up by the oil = $10^{-5}\text{ N} = 4 \text{ cm/s}$, but the only way to get this answer is through applying both forces, not subtracting.

Comment: further hint:at dynamic equilibrium with no acceleration the net force is zero.

Comment: I understand that friction takes out acceleration at 4cm/s velocity. At my hand I can see 4cm/s equals 100*10^-6N friction, but I don't understand how the pinball can reach such speed when it's force down is 5.69*10^-5N? The only way I saw this happening was by applying Oil force + The pinball, which...kinda makes no sense? Sorry if i'm a noob.

Comment: Net force is zero at terminal velocity meaning DragForce = Weight (gravitational force). You just have a sign problem. Think real hard about the directions of the two forces. If you call gravity 'DOWN' then the resisting drag force must be in the opposite direction, 'UP' (since it resists the downward weight)

Comment: BTW I didn't down vote you (but I also didnt upvote). You obviously needed help and I don't penalize that.

Comment: And one more thing. Yes books can sometimes be wrong. Authors, scientists are people and they can make mistakes. Learn to think clearly, trust your instincts, and question when you believe things might be amiss.

Comment: I know :S, I end up nutting for eternity in both Programming and Physics when something just won't work, I guess i'm professional at wasting time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is dynamic in that the ball accelerates under the force of gravity, initially at rest but then reaching a steady state, [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity), similar to what a skydiver experiences when jumping from an aircraft.

The terminal velocity is reached when the force of gravity is in balance (equilibrated) with the viscous drag force imposed by the flow of oil past the ball. At that point, the acceleration is zero and velocity is constant. This equilibrium offers the opportunity of solving the terminal velocity without having to deal with the acceleration simply by equating the two forces at play.

That's the physics, but I'll leave it to you to solve the problem since its a homework problem.

And by the way, the ball moving in oil within a tube has a very practical application in the control of satellites. Curved tubes with either gas or oil and a ball bearing can be placed in a spinning satellite. Spinning can eventually lead to precession and [nutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutation). The passive nutation dampers can be used to arrest and dampen the nutation.